# Why checkbox of android is so slow？

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Today, I used an Android machine with poor performance. I found the checkbox loading is very slow.
For example:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("main cost: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()  - t1));
    }
}
```

There is only one Checkbox in the page, this will cost 200ms. If there are 3 or 5 checkbox in activity_main.xml, will cost 1s. What happend?

I compared Switch to Checkbox. Obviously Switch is very very better than Checkbox. If i want to keep to use Checkbox, what should i do?

Comment: why dont you try using `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I'm not the author of the question but the bounty-starter. I've tried your suggestion, but it makes no difference in speed, unfortunately.

Comment: I know.ok I will try other things and let you know

Comment: what about a `custom layout` with one `ImageView` and one `TextView`?

Comment: how are you measuring the speed ?and what will happen if there is 200-300 mills lag?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I have a [`ListFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/ListFragment) (Fragment with a ListView) with a custom list item layout: `ConstraintLayout > [Checkbox <-> TextView <-> ImageView]`. If the list gets loaded with a screen full of items (about 12 items) it's very slow and `I/Choreographer` often complains that it skipped from 50 to about 200 frames. If I replace the `CheckBox` with a `Switch`, the items load almost immediately and it never skips frames.

Comment: actually the reason is that checkbox has a very very big class.if you open it, you see thousands of lines of code! what about a `custom layout` with one `ImageView` and one `TextView? `–

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal Ah, you mean create a custom checkbox by using an `ImageView` (for the box and check mark) and `TextView` (for the label)? If so: yeah, that could work of course, but before rolling my own, I was curious if somebody had some other ideas. Also: I've opened the `CheckBox` class and with me it's only about 20 lines of code (just some constructors). And although it extends `CompoundButton`, so does `Switch`. So I don't understand why `CheckBox` is so slow. What class file did you look at? I looked at `Sdk/android-28/android/widget/CheckBox.java`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your situation but can not reproduce it.
I get arround 40 - 50ms for both cases for switch and for checkbox. I tried with compileSdk 30 and compileSdk 32. On physical device Samsung Galaxy S20.
Can you put more information with build.gradle and on which device was tested?

Answer (score 4):

### Why does it happen ?

---

This is happening because the `Checkbox` class is very complicated(too much useless code on the main thread).

### What is the solution ?

---

1. You can create a custom layout.
2. You can use a library.

### How to implement ?

---

#### 1.Custom layout

- First create a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation.
- Add an `ImageView` and a `TextView` in the xml.
- Code reference

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="7dp">
        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkImageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/checked"/>
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the text for checkbox."
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
        
</LinearLayout>
```

- Now the code for it to work.

In your class add this

```
boolean isChecked = true
```

Now it will function like this

```
LinearLayout checkBox = findViewById( R.id.checkbox );
        ImageView checkBoxImage = findViewById( R.id.checkImageView );
        checkBox.setOnClickListener( v -> {
            final Bitmap bmap = ((BitmapDrawable)checkBoxImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checked);
            final Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
            if (bmap.sameAs(myLogo)){
                //it is checked
                isChecked = false;
                checkBoxImage.setImageResource( R.drawable.unchecked );
            }else {
                isChecked = true;
                checkBoxImage.setImageResource( R.drawable.checked );
            }
        } );
```

---

#### 2.Using a library

- Use [this](https://github.com/iGenius-Srl/android-custom-checkbox) library.

[image]

#### Sample usage

```
setChecked(boolean checked); //by default, it's wthout animation
setChecked(boolean checked, boolean animate);  //pass true to animate
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    final CustomCheckBox scb = (CustomCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.scb);
    scb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CustomCheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CustomCheckBox checkBox, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("CustomCheckBox", String.valueOf(isChecked));
        }
    });
}
```

#### Attributes

| Attr | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| duration | integer | Animation Duration |
| stroke_width | dimension | The border width when unchecked |
| color_tick | color | Tick color (visible only when checked) |
| color_checked | color | Fill color when selected |
| color_unchecked | color | Fill color when unchecked |
| color_unchecked_stroke | color | Border color when unchecked |

### References

---

[Github](https://github.com/iGenius-Srl/android-custom-checkbox)

### Edit 1 (27/1/22)

---

Because of the comment received by `Decent Dabbler` , I now remember what it forgot. I actually forgot to mention that the file that takes too long to load is the `xml` file.This can be proved as we do not always use the class right? Just the view in the `xml`. If you open the `xml` file of the checkbox, you find it too big.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your input. Great answer! I will definitively check out the component on GitHub, too. However, I still don't get why `CheckBox` lags so much and `Switch` does not, since both classes extend `CompoundButton`. Perhaps it has something to do with the layout file of `CheckBox`? Maybe that does some extremely complex stuff behind the scenes.

Comment: i have now edited my answer and added why it lags.I guess you were checking the `java` class. But all the code i am talking about is the `xml`.

Comment: does this clarify your question?

Comment: I can't seem to find the xml file that you are referring to in the SDK. What is the location of the xml file? The biggest files ending with `checkbox.xml` that I could find in the SDKs were only `1.6kB` large. Basically just one or two xml tags with some attributes, nothing more.

Comment: well.leave it. it took me a lot of time to find it. and now it is missing again.if I find, I will let you know

Comment: I decided to create a `CheckableImageView` class, because I didn't need a text label. It's based on bits and pieces of your answer and on `androidx.leanback.widget.CheckableImageView` that I accidentally came across while digging through the SDKs. And yeah, it works very smooth.

Comment: glad you found a solution